# Is there a way to setup ping check for remote host in Azure?

Tags: azure, ping, healthcheck, alert

I'm trying to find a way in Azure to setup some service to be able to do ping check on remote host not hosted in Azure and alert when it is not reachable. For example On-Premises server with PIP.

Answer (score 1):

You can onboard on-prem machines using the log analytics agent, which will then send heatbeat messages to log analytics, which you can alert on.

Comment: Hey, thnx for quick response. Actually I'm looking for agent-less solution. The only check I want to have is: ping.

Comment: There isn't really a service that will do this. App Insights has availiblity checks, but these focus on http.